# Send multiple dynamic emails through Sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I would like to know if it's possible to send multiple dynamic emails using Sendgrid's SMTP-API.

I know it is possible to send one email body to several recipients, passing user data through substitutions, but what if the email body is different for each user?

Imagine you send an email to one user with an image1.jpeg and then an email with image2.jpeg, image3.jpeg and image4.jpeg to a different user.

Basically, I want to be able to send multiple emails with dynamic content per user.

Is this possible with Rails? Or Java?

Thanks.

Comment: I would think it is possible in just about any language.  Just iterate through whatever and modify what you want to for each email.

Comment: Yes, of course, but how would you render all of them to send it to Sendgrid using their API? As far as I can tell, you can only send 1 body format to all users with one SMTPAPI call. So bluntly speaking it would be     `[body],[user1,user2,user3..usern]`      but I want `[body1,body2,body3...bodyn],[user1,user2,user3...usern]`.

Comment: In Rails it is pretty straightforward.  Just search for `ActionMailer` and you should find plenty of examples.  Basically, you can create a template for the email body (both text and html) and then use ERB to interpolate dynamic data in the message before sending.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I already have a template and `ActionMailer` already working but I only send one email per `SMTP` connection which comes to 1 email a second per worker (lots of stuff in the email). Of course this is not acceptable so I wanted to know if there's a way to render and send multiple emails Through Sendgrid's API.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Template Engine](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Template_Engine/smtpapi.html).

Create a template via the UI at https://sendgrid.com/templates or [via the API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Template_Engine/templates.html#-POST).

Then enable the "templates" filter in your X-SMTPAPI header with the template of the id you create:

```
{
  "filters": {
    "templates": {
      "settings": {
        "enable": 1,
        "template_id": "5997fcf6-2b9f-484d-acd5-7e9a99f0dc1f"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you'll use the SMTP API substitutions and sections for your dynamic content. [There's an example combining this with template engine templates.](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Template_Engine/smtpapi.html#-Substitutions-and-Sections)

Comment: Yes, I saw the documentation about the Template Engine but I'm still in doubt if it's possible to do what I want to. Currently I render the emails as suggested on Sendgrid's X-SMTP API but only one email each time. By using the Template Engine, I believe Sendgrid would do the rendering for me, right? But the catch is, currently, I have an array in my template and it creates a `<table>` for each element in that array. but that array changes for each user, for each email. Is this possible using the Template API? If so, how would it be possible? Can I have any kind of scripting in the template?

Comment: Template Engine does not have any iterators currently, but they are planned in the next version. You could process your content ahead of time and pass it as sections, which would let you send multiple emails with one API request.

Comment: I haven't thought about the sections but that makes a lot of sense to me and might be able to do the trick! That's great to hear that it's planned. Do you have some sort of estimate on when you think it will be out?